# UIAlert does not working with NSNotification

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotification

I put Reachability.swift file in my app, when Internet reachability is changed, I want to alert to user that internet connection is not available.

this is my code.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController {
var reachability : Reachability?
var myAlert = UIAlertController()

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    do {
        let reachability = try Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
        self.reachability = reachability
    } catch ReachabilityError.FailedToCreateWithAddress(let address) {

    }
    catch {}


NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "HeyUserInternetDoesntWork", name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)

     }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func saveButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let save = PFObject(className: "Practice")
    save["text"] = textField.text
    save.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        print("Object has been saved.")
    }

}


   dynamic func HeyUserInternetDoesntWork() {


    if reachability!.isReachable() {


    } else {


         myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "No internet", message: "no good", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
        myAlert.addAction(okAction)        }
}
```

}

this is not working, I got an error that

> Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behaviour

I don't understand what this mean.
If I put code that print("unreachable") will work fine.

**My question**

what is meaning of that error?

How I can make my alert works?

If there is other way to let user know Internet connectivity,

please let me know.

Comment: if you have defined alert from `UIAlertViewController` like that without using it or in the class variable!

Comment: I declare this code, var myAlert = UIAlertController() on the UILabel deflation above ////  but still, I have same error

Comment: try your reachibility in viewDidAppear once not in viewDidLoad

Comment: the reason before loading all objects in your view some objects memory are relased thats why , now it works bro or not

Comment: oh yeah, I got it. but it still doesn't work. it is good to know! thank you though!

Comment: now also you faceing the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add this line under alert
(self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil))

Comment: after I delete var myAlert = UIAlertController(), it works fine.